# Desktop Duplication API vs Windows.Graphics.Capture

Tags: windows, winapi, screen-capture

I'm writing a screen recording app for a specific game, with focus on performance, support for older versions of windows is irrelevant, so it seems that using either of the two APIs is valid compatibility wise, but I can't find much data on performance, afaik NVIDIA deprecated NVFBC in favor of DDA https://developer.download.nvidia.com/designworks/capture-sdk/docs/NVFBC_Win10_Deprecation_Tech_Bulletin.pdf, according to the document, DDA with GPU encoding (whether NVENC or equivalent) seems quite good performance wise, where does Windows.Graphics.Capture fit in all of this, I know it's newer but is it more performant, I can't run my own benchmarks, because I'm not familiar with either of the APIs and I could introduce an error or simply by coding either sub optimally I may end up simply with comparing the performance of my implementation instead of the API, the game is mostly CPU bound on most systems, so for most users the GPU would have spare power for encoding, also aside from performance what are the benefits & drawbacks of using either of the aforementioned APIs

Comment: Windows.Graphics.Capture uses the same technology as DXGI Desktop Duplication API underneath, plus it can capture a windows (HWND) which is today not exposed by DXGI Desktop Duplication API for some (stupid) reason. So I would definitely got for it unless you already have a heavy DXGI/DirectX/etc. codebase (and you don't need window capture)

Comment: @SimonMourier according to this https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/windows-graphics-capture-vs-dxgi-desktop-duplication.149320/ "The main benefit of WGC capture is that it works cross-GPU with no user intervention. DXGI requires OBS to run on the same GPU as the display." which would imply there's a difference in it's underlying technology, am I mistaken?

Comment: Don't know what this means, maybe solely related to OBS. Like I said, Windows.Graphics.Capture uses the same tech but it's like vNext of it. Ask in this forums if you think they know better